# I used a drop down box to load different text box based on option from drop down box but unable to get default view

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I used a drop down box named dd1 to display the list of cards like select card,visa,master cards.when i use select card as default view in dd1, i should not get any text boxes displayed and when visa or master cards are selected it should display text boxes and labels asking name and card number etc. i am able to get the labels and textboxes when selected visa or master but could not get the default view on selection of select card(which is first option in dd1)
this is the code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
     <asp:ListItem Text="---Select amount" Selected="True" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Master card" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Maestro" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Visa" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Visa Debit" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Post office Credit card" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:MultiView ID="multiview" ActiveViewIndex="-1" runat="server">
     <asp:View ID="viewtext" runat="server">
          <p>
             <asp:Label ID="cardname" runat="server" Text="Name on card"></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
          </p>
          <p>
             <asp:Label ID="cardnumber" runat="server" Text="Card number"></asp:Label>
             <asp:TextBox ID="text2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </p>
```

Code behind is as follows:

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (IsPostBack)
       return;
   }
   protected void dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (dd1.SelectedValue=="1")
       {
          multiview.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
       }

   }
}
```

Please help me with this..Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working on my side. like below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
            <asp:ListItem Text="---Select amount" Selected="True" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Master card" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Maestro" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Visa" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Visa Debit" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Post office Credit card" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:MultiView ID="multiview" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="viewtext" runat="server">
                <p>
                    Default View
                </p>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
                <p>
                 Master card
                </p>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view2" runat="server">
                <p>
                   Maestro
                </p>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view3" runat="server">
                <p>
                    Visa
                </p>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view4" runat="server">
                <p>
                    Visa Debit
                </p>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view5" runat="server">
                <p>
                   Post office Credit card
                </p>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```

Code

```
 protected void dd1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dd1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                multiview.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt16(dd1.SelectedValue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: its working with my example also but i am unable to load default view that is when i didnot select any type of card and use default select type in drop down it should hide all text box but its not doing so.. thats my problem